# problems with the function set_weights()

Tags: python, keras

I have an array of weights that I am trying to install on my model. Constantly stumble on one and the same mistake. Please tell me how to properly do it.

I only managed to get tired of weight. Although this works, but the number of scales may increase and it will not be convenient to constantly change the code to resolve this issue.

```py
model.set_weights([array([[x[number][0]]], dtype=float32), array([x[number][1]], dtype=float32)])

def baseline_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear', input_dim=1))
    model.compile(optimizer=optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001), loss='mean_squared_error')
    return model


def fitness(x):
    model = baseline_model()
    model.set_weights(x)
    y_predict = model.predict(data)
    return K.eval(losses.mean_squared_error(y, np.ravel(y_predict)))


x = [0.5, 0.6]
fitness(x)
```

> ValueError: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 0 for 'Assign' (op: 'Assign') with input shapes: [1,1], [].

Comment: What is the actual shape of z that you are passing to set_weights?

Comment: Sorry, i make mistake. There is x